# Interpreting Pearson vs Spearman correlations

Tags: correlation, python, pearson-r, spearman-rho

(Disclaimer: I'm a programmer, not a statistician. I'm learning about this stuff in a Data Science course. Consider me technically savvy and statistically clueless.)

The data and plots here are part of an ongoing project. This piece of the project asks: "what can you do with statistics?"

I'm asking: "Is there a correlation between various variables"?

My data (Oxygen v Chlorophyll in the samples) plots like this:

[image]

As Chlorophyll + Photosynthesis produces O2, I figured I'd see if the data shows a correlation.

Here's my output:

```
Covariance matrix:
 [[53.26027301  2.13119576]
 [ 2.13119576  1.03124445]]

Pearsons correlation: 0.288

Spearmans correlation: -0.101
```

Both Pearsons and Spearmans show a weak correlation, but in opposite directions.

What, if anything, can I take away from this?

Comment: Spearman and Pearson correlation don't examine the same relationship, so they can have different signs. However, the relationship does not appear to be linear (Pearson) or monotonic (Spearman), so naturally the calculations will give weak values. (They better!) It would be helpful if you could say more about your goal.

Comment: You have been misled by the language.  In the question, "correlation" is used in a colloquial sense to mean "relationship" or "association."  Please do not take that to mean you must compute or analyze any kind of "correlation coefficient."  Indeed, that's going to be a dead end for these data.  You need to learn about and apply nonlinear regression models.

Comment: Thank you......